# X does not work after the update (Solved)

Tags: greeter, xorg

I just updated my elementary OS install, and now Xorg does not work.  I am able to make it into the login screen, but when trying to sign in it goes back to the sign-in form.  So I decided to try `Control+Alt+F1` to log in to the terminal, which I can.  But when trying to start X, it says:

```
xinit: server error
Xauth: timeout in locking authority file /home/pookito/.Xauthority
```

This file seems to me a binary file or something.  When I run `ls -l .Xauthority`, I can see that root can read and write to it, but that's it. If I try to do `cat . Xauthority`, something about magic-cookie in all caps comes up.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try stopping lightdm(the login screen) with `sudo systemctl stop lightdm` from tty1, then `sudo su` to login as root and delete the .Xauthority file with `rm -f ./.Xauthority` and then reboot. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Dude, you are my brother.  Thank you for the quick reply.  It is working now.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please vote it as a solution, so others can easily fix a common issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop lightdm (the login screen) with
`sudo systemctl stop lightdm` from tty1;
then run
`sudo su`
 to login as root; then delete the .Xauthority file with
`rm -f ./.Xauthority`,
 and then reboot.